# When I try to run the executable on Linux I get "error while loading shared libraries"

Tags: linux, libraries, cppunit

inlc6500> ./CDG
./CDG: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_regex.so.1.46.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can any1 tell what is the solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package that provides the library for the architecture the executable has been built for.

Comment: which is hopefully the same as the machine architecture ;-)

Comment: You get a different error if the machine cannot run the executable due to architecture differences.